# Edit custom options select box content

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options

I have added custom option in product as selectbox. Its showing fine on frontend but in select box **+** sign  its showing. Is there a way to remove **+** Sign Symobl

[image: Select Box here]

Select Box options are

-- Please Select --

400x600x300 **+** Rs1,992.00

450x600x300 **+** Rs2,121.00

I have change `js/varien/configurable.js` 
changed this line

```
var str = '';
    price = parseFloat(price);
    if(showSign){
        if(price<0){
            str+= '-';
            price = -price;
        }
        else{
            str+= '+'; **to**
            str+= ' '; 
        }
    }
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

The "+" sign indicates that there is an additional charge for the custom option in addition to the product price.

If you set a price to the custom option, the "+" sign will appear together with the price. This is actually a good thing indicating your customers that there is an extra price for the option.

Here's how to find out, where the "+" sign comes from and how to change it:

First: Enable template hints form the backend and add Block names:

- System > Configuration > Developer > Debug > Template Path Hints
- System > Configuration > Developer > Debug > Add Block Names

From there you can see, that the template `frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\options\type\select.phtml` with its block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select` is used.

In the Template, the `getValuesHtml()` method is called from the block.

The `getValuesHtml()` method contains a call to `_formatPrice()`:

```
foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(array(
                    'is_percent'    => ($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice(($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'))
                ), false);
}
```

`_formatPrice()` is a function of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Abstract` where the "+" sign is set:

```
protected function _formatPrice($value, $flag=true)     {
    ...
        $sign = '+';
    ...
}
```

**How to change it:**

Please do not edit core files (PHP or JavaScript) of your Magento installation.

The best way would be to declare a new block (in a base-module you have or a new one), for example `YourNamespace_YourModule_Product_View_Options_Type_Select` which extends from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select` where you override the protected `_formatPrice()` function.

You will then need to change the block in your local.xml:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" ...>
...
<action method="addOptionRenderer">
<type>select</type>
<block>yourmodule/product_view_options_type_select</block>
<template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template>
</action>
...
</block>
```